# r %in% operator behavior for data table factors?

Tags: r, data.table

I can't seem to get the %in% operator to behave for data table factor columns. I know I'm probably missing some secret syntax for data tables, but I can't to find it... I've searched all over.

Here's a tiny example illustrating my pain. Of course the simple answer would be to use data frames, but I have a large data set that benefits from some features of data tables.

```
> a <- data.table(c1=factor(c(1,2,3)))
> a
   c1
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3

> '2' %in% a[,1,with=F]
[1] FALSE

> 2 %in% a[,1,with=F]
[1] FALSE
```

and it works like I expect for data frames...

```
> b <- data.frame(c1=factor(c(1,2,3)))
> '2' %in% b[,1]
[1] TRUE
```

Any help appreciated....

Comment: This all sumes up to the fact that `data.table` doesn't have `drop` argument while `data.frame` does. In other words, If you would to select more than one column you would get similar behaviour from both.

Comment: Btw. I'd expect using `%in%` to match against a data.table column of decent size to be quite slow. There are probably better alternatives for your actual goal.

Comment: @Roland probably. But I'm not too adept at optimizing R. The factor in question has 3 values and about 20k rows. I only need to know if any() appear in the column. Suggestions welcome. :) And thanks for the original answer.

Comment: Well, then you should compare with the `levels` possibly after using `droplevels`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a[,1,with=F]` is a data.table and not a vector like `b[,1]`. This is documented.

A data.table is a list and `help("%in%")` says that "lists are converted to character vectors". So, I'd guess this happens (but it's hidden in the C source code of `match`):

```
as.character(a[,1,with=F])
#[1] "1:3"
```

You can select data.table columns efficiently with `[[`:

```
'2' %in% a[[1]]
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I was aware of selecting columns with `[[`, but didn't mention in my problem that I also needed to filter some rows. So I was using the syntax `a[myrows,1,with=F]`. So now I've switched to something like `a[myrows][[1]]`.